# Screen Capture VNC in WPF Loop

Tags: c#, wpf

this maybe something obvious hopefully, I'm trying to perform screen capture in WPF similar to VNC and I get the following:

Could someone inform me of what is going on here and how to solve it please?

[image]

The code that implements this is as follows:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
 timer.Elapsed += this.Timer_Elapsed;

 timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
 var image = this.CaptureScreen(0, 0, SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);

 Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
 {
     img.Source = BitmapToImageSource(image);
 });
}

public Bitmap CaptureScreen(double x, double y, double width, double height)
{
 int ix, iy, iw, ih;

 ix = Convert.ToInt32(x);
 iy = Convert.ToInt32(y);
 iw = Convert.ToInt32(width);
 ih = Convert.ToInt32(height);

 var image = new Bitmap(iw, ih, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

 var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

 graphics.CopyFromScreen(ix, iy, ix, iy, new System.Drawing.Size(iw, ih), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

 return image;
}

private BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
 using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
 {
     bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
     memory.Position = 0;

     var bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
     bitmapimage.BeginInit();
     bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
     bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
     bitmapimage.EndInit();

     return bitmapimage;
 }
}
```

Comment: "*what is going on here*" - you are taking a screenshot of the entire screen including the window of your application. Then you put the screenshot in an Image in your application and take the next screenshot.

Comment: I did guess that is what is going on, but why?

Comment: Because you have programmed it so.